# How to add dynamic connection string in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

Can someone help me on achieving dynamic connections to databases using azure data factory?

Comment: Please add more detail on what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried and possibly some examples of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

> achieving dynamic connections to databases using azure data factory

Based on this document [Parameterize linked services in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services),so far,you can now parameterize a linked service and pass dynamic values at run time.

[image]

It supports Cosmos DB:

[image]

BTW,MS recommends not to parameterize passwords or secrets. Store all connection strings in Azure Key Vault instead, and parameterize the Secret Name.About details,please see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault).

---

***Update Answer:***

As for db name,of course you can parameterize it.

You could configure dynamic db name when you create cosmos db linked service.

[image]

Click dynamic content and create new parameter.

[image]

---

***Update Answer2:***

Please refer to this [sdk function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.operations.linked_services_operations.linkedservicesoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-resource-group-name--factory-name--linked-service-name--properties--if-match-none--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) and my working code as below:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import *

# Azure subscription ID
subscription_id = '***'

# This program creates this resource group. If it's an existing resource group, comment out the code that creates the resource group
rg_name = '***'

# The data factory name. It must be globally unique.
df_name = '***'

# Specify your Active Directory client ID, client secret, and tenant ID
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id='***',
                                          secret='***',
                                          tenant='***')
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

resource_client.resource_groups.get(rg_name)

# Create a data factory
df_resource = Factory(location='eastus')
df = adf_client.factories.get(rg_name, df_name, df_resource)
print(df)

ls_name = 'testlink1'
dbName = "<your db name>"

connection_string = 'AccountEndpoint=https://***.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=***;Database='+dbName+';';

ls_cosmos_db = CosmosDbLinkedService(connection_string=connection_string)
ls = adf_client.linked_services.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, ls_name, ls_cosmos_db)
print(ls)
```

More details, you could refer to official [create linked service example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python#create-a-linked-service) and python sdk for [ADF management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.linkedservice?view=azure-python).

[image]

Comment: Hi Jay, i'm trying to parameterize Db name. Such that i specify the same in ADF and we should be able to connect to respective DB based on the parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the response that'll help. However can i pass this parameter to python script?

Comment: @Nomad18 Hi,Nomad18. I test the code as above,please see update answer 2.Hope it helps you.